# Custom class for lists

Tags: c#, class, methods

**I have** built a custom calendar control (like google calendar and outlook calendar)

**I want to** add the functionality to handle events(Add, remove, etc). I already have it, but I want it to feel as generic as possible.

*How my code currently looks:*

```
myCalendar.Events.Add(myEvent);
myCalendar.Draw //this adds all the events to the calendar
```

*Example of what I think looks more generic:*

```
myCalendar.Events.Add(myEvent);
myCalendar.Events.Remove(unwantedEvent);
myCalendar.Events.Draw
```

**My question.** Is the second code-snippet best practice or should I just go with a separate class for handling drawing and such. (which I currently have)

If the second snippet is better, ***how do I go about doing so?***

*Rough Example of one of the methods I've tried (to give you an idea of what I want to accomplish)*

```
public _Events Events = new _Events();

public class _Events
{
    public List<Event> Events = new List<Event>();

    void Add(...)
    {
        //Add event to Events
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Event
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that i want to be able to return a default value like so...

```
listOfEvents =  myCalendar.Events
```

*Disclaimer: I have tried in vain to find a solution, but couldn't find the right keywords to find it*

Comment: Semantically, are you drawing the *events*, or are you drawing the *calendar*?  It makes sense to me that `Calendar` and `Event` would be domain objects with no concept of "drawing" and that another class, something like a `CalendarRenderer` in the UI layer, would accept a `Calendar` and have the means to draw it.

Comment: Is myCalendar a user control for windows forms?

Comment: @David I am drawing the events onto the calendar

Comment: I'd also suggest that `Event` should be an abstract class so you can create `MeeingEvent` or `BirthdayEvent` etc, allowing the renderer to render differently based on the type.

Comment: I can't imaging what "draw event" means... I'd expect calendar to simply get updated with new events when one added/removed without any additional actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to handle your code snippet, so I pulled out some code that I use to store custom objects that get rendered to a view.  You can use code in the class to process how data gets returned when you use an accessor.

```
using System.ComponentModel;    
public abstract class DiagramObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //the actual variable
    private string _name;

    //how the variable is accessed and set
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    //
    public string AbbreviatedName
    {
        get
        {
            if (_name.Length>=1)
            {
                return _name.Substring(0, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                return "NA";
            }        
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

These are then made accessible to use for display by creating an observable collection and initializing.  If you are using WPF, it can then be bound to a listbox.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
private ObservableCollection<DiagramObject> _objects;
public ObservableCollection<DiagramObject> Objects
{
    get { return _nodes ?? (_nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>()); }
}

public MainClass
{
    _objects = new ObservableCollection<DiagramObject>(constructor that makes the objects);
}
```

I pulled a large amount of code for my project from https://github.com/High-Core/WPFSamples/tree/master/src/WPFSamples/Samples .   This is being added to by the person who makes it and has a lot of really interesting work.